# AJAX: Getting the title of the loaded html document (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am loading an html page within the body of a landing page via jquery and ajax. I need the `<title>Page Title</title>` from the loaded document for the landing page.

I have tried this, but no luck:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.htm",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
            $('#main-load').html(html);
            $('#greeting').append($(html).find('title').text());
        }
});
```

I have also tried a few other methods, but no luck. Any ideas?

Thank you!

EDIT:
test.htm is a very simple document.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
....
</style>
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you put a summary of the code "test.htm?

Comment: The `html` method will strip the head from the document before it inserts it. This is necessary to avoid breaking. Not sure what a good workaround would be - you may have to parse the raw data

Comment: @Pekka: He's not looking in the inserted tree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Pekka said, it does strip the head from the loaded document, so you'll have to parse it out of the raw text with a regular expression: (Let me know if this works)

```
var title = html.match("<title>(.*?)</title>")[1];
```

Comment: @Sunburnt Ginger, just fixed a bug in the above code. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to find for `title` after you have appended to `main-load`.

`$('#greeting').append($('#main-load').find('title').text());`

Answer (score -2):

try to use this code:

```
$(html).attr("title");
```

Hope it works

Comment: No bueno... returns a null value. Thanks though!

Comment: Needing to get the `title` element not a `title` attribute.